# How to use Saxon XSLT engine with Altova XmlSpy?

Tags: xslt, saxon, xmlspy

Is it possible to use Saxon in XmlSpy (2013 PE) for XSLT processing? There's a setting for external EXE program, but Saxon being Java doesn't play well here.

[image]

Comment: Assuming XML Spy is a Windows application you could try the .NET version of Saxon and use the `Transform.exe` you have with .NET. Or figure out the command line path for running Saxon Java with the Oracle Java JRE e.g. `java.exe -jar C:\Programs\Saxonica\saxon9pe.jar %1 %2`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen literally just got the same working on my end!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, just figured this out (consistent with Martins comment above using `java -jar`):

```
java -jar <fullPathToJar>/saxon9.jar -s:%1 -o:%2 -xsl:%3
-s    xml source file
-o    output file
-xsl  (optional) xsl file
```

[image]